# How do I copy/paste a command on mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I want to know how to select, copy the entire command from a command block (separately) and paste it into the chat or an another command block on *Mac*.
I've already took a look to the other question similars, none of them responded at what I had in thought correctly. Thank you.

Comment: I feel this is more of a computing question than related to minecraft.

Comment: I don't know the differences are between mac and windows, but can you use Shift+left or Shift+right to select text? From there, if mac has a copy hotkey (like ctrl+C for windows) you can copy the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same commands you use outside Minecraft to copy/paste on a Mac:

- Paste: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- Copy: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Cut: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Select all: <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Select part of text per symbol: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> *or* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> (In the direction you want to select the
  text)
- Select part of text per word: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> *or* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> (In the direction you want to select the
  text)

These shortcuts work inside the chat, in Command Blocks and most other text fields ingame. They do not work with signs, unfortunately

Comment: This unfortunately don't works. I think that my game got a bug or something like this.

Comment: I've made a second question, because my mac seem to don't accept this way of copy/paste/select in minecraft:

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263244/mac-minecraft-copy-paste-select-problem

Answer (score 2):

**For 1.8 and above**, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy, and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste, just like the rest of the operating system.

To select all text, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

---

**For below 1.8**, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to copy and paste inside Minecraft. To copy and paste outside, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. If you want to copy outside of Minecraft to inside, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> outside then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> inside, and vice versa.

To select all text, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Comment: It does not works

Comment: @Kimatuy I do not believe this works for chat, but correct me if I'm wrong. But it should work for command blocks.

Comment: This only applies to older Minecraft versions.

Comment: @nelson2tm Thanks! It turns out I answered that with 1.7 knowledge. Fixed it now, but your answer is better, honestly. I up-voted it :)

Comment: @Kimatuy OK, it should work now. I made a mistake. But also check out nelson2tm's answer below, it's better, with more shortcuts.