# Copy/paste/select problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, macos

I've been asking question about this, but it seems that my Minecraft on Mac can't accept to copy/paste/select from Minecraft to Minecraft itself or from Minecraft to my Mac; however, I can copy from my Mac to Minecraft using `Cmd + v`.

For more precision, I am using the latest version of Minecraft, the `1.9.2`, my Mac computer version is the`MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015)`, and my Mac system version is the `OS X El Capitan`.

Comment: Works fine for me (also running `El Capitan`). Are you sure you used `Cmd` + `C` and `Cmd` + `V`? On a Dell keyboard it's the Windows logo.

Comment: May be it's a bug. And if it is one, it is a damn bug. It makes me lose time, sadly. For the one who mark my question as duplicated, I have to tell you that THIS is exactly my problem: Why it work on the others and not mine?

Comment: If you want, I can try to help you on chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can use ctrl-c inside of minecraft to copy/paste something; and when you want to copy/paste from minecraft to mac osx, use ctrl-c inside of minecraft and Cmd-v outside of minecraft in mac osx.

Comment: Nope, it wouldn't work.